# What can I use to enable-disable a ssh tunnel with port forwarding?

Tags: network, ssh

I already found a product that does this, named Meerkat, but I'm looking for a free solution.

I need to do several port remapping with ease.

Answer (score 4):

Aliases and a bash script? Or the following:

- [SSH Tunnel Manager](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/stm/) (free, open source)
- [Cocoa-SSHTunnel](https://code.google.com/p/cocoa-sshtunnel/) (GPL)
- [SSH Keychain](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/) (GPL)

Answer (score 1):

I've had pretty good success with SSH Tunnel Manager. It's now available on the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ssh-tunnel-manager/id424470626?mt=12). I have some clients who use it to tunnel FileMaker Pro across the internet.